# How to click links and fire mousedown/mouseup events by javascript

Tags: javascript, events, mouse

I'm working on a bookmarklet to open links from a page but it also needs to fire mousedown/mouseup events ... I made the bookmarklet to click and open links but can't make it to fire mouse events :( ...

```
javascript:(function(){
        function clickLink(link) {
            if (document.createEvent) {
                var event=document.createEvent("MouseEvents"); 
                event.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
                link.dispatchEvent(event);
            } else if (link.fireEvent) {
                link.fireEvent("onclick");
            }
        } 
        l=document.links;
        for(var i=0;i<l.length;++i) {
                 clickLink(l[i]);
};})();
```

Please Help! ... Thanks in advance!

Comment: What browser does this fail in?